# Is it allowed to publish framework files built with old xcode to the store?

Tags: ios, xcode

Today, we've released instructions to use xcode 12 GM SEED for apps that apple publishes to the store.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=itpt8dkc

When a new iOS is released, it is often instructed to build using the latest xcode like this.
Does this also apply to framework files?

I'm using a framework file in my project that updates slowly.
The .framework file I'm using at the moment is probably built with xcode 11 and SDK 13.
Is it possible to incorporate this framework file into my app and publish it to the store?
It would be more helpful if it was the official document of apple